# React + Redux: how to force Loading element to exist at least 0.5 seconds

Tags: reactjs, redux

Let's say it's common for my app to have such component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Loading from './Loading'

export default class Form extends Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    const { propogateValues, isFetching, fetchPath } = this.props
    console.log(this.props)
    if (isFetching) {
      propogateValues(fetchPath)
    }
  }
  render () {
    const { handleSubmit, path, successPush, isFetching } = this.props
    if (isFetching) {
      return (<div> <Loading /></div>)
    } else {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={(e) => { handleSubmit(e, path, successPush) }}>
          {this.props.children}
        </form>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Where `Loading` is pure presentational component representing loading animation.

Issue: when receive action is dispatched and component receives new  `isFetching: false` prop, it rerenders component. However, from interface perspective, I would like `Loading` to exist at least some time (.5 second), because very fast switch makes it looks worse than without such component at all.

Not sure how to implement it, should I really use redux store here or there is better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding [react-delay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-delay) component should help create the effect.

```
<div>
  <Delay wait={500}>
    <Loading />
  </Delay>
</div>
```

The [source code for Delay](https://github.com/chrisshiplet/react-delay/blob/master/src/Delay.js) is quite simple to understand.

Comment: Does this solution really work? because I see there is an if statement in the question code, and when `isFetching` is `false` the hold `<div>` block will be remove not just the `<Loading />` component.